# CIFS randomly losing connection to Windows share

Tags: debian, cifs, smb

I have had a couple of directories mounted remotely from a Debian Jessie, in a Windows share, for a few months.

In the last weeks, I keep having complaints of random disconnects from the mountpoint, and had to do a

```
sudo mount -a
```

to regain the mount connectivity, a couple of times (the server is used once or twice a week).

e.g. the mounts are not recovering often after some period without being used.

The Windows administrator also told me the Windows server has not been rebooted for a while.

Today, coincidentally when doing `mount -a` again, it only worked in the 2nd try, while the first try gave the following error:

```
sudo mount -a
mount error(104): Connection reset by peer
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The directories are mounted from `/etc/fstab` as such:

`//10.2.1.2/XX/ZZ/YY    /mnt/mount_point        cifs    credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0`

When doing a mount command, you can also see the option `echo_interval` is activated by default at 60 seconds.

`$mount
//10.2.1.2/XX/ZZ/YY on /mnt/mount_point type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=someusername,domain=XXX,uid=1001,forceuid,gid=1001,forcegid,addr=10.2.1.2,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`

What to do?

Comment: `echo_interval 60`  Here 60 is the echo interval in seconds not minutes. [man](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/cifs-utils/mount.cifs.8.en.html)

Comment: @Pieter Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found an interesting related post here [cifs mounted folder keeps disconnecting (ubuntu server)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366731/cifs-mounted-folder-keeps-disconnecting-ubuntu-server/367874), talking of a similar problem (same error, Samba shares).

The relevant tidbit here, for following the rest of the answer, is that CIFS mounts use the SMBv1.0 protocol by default, as can be verified issuing the `mount`command, and paying attention to the `vers=1.0` field.

`$mount
//10.2.1.2/XX/ZZ/YY on /mnt/mount_point type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=someusername,domain=XXX,uid=1001,forceuid,gid=1001,forcegid,addr=10.2.1.2,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`

I also found in Stack Overflow, the post [Mount CIFS Host is down](https://serverfault.com/questions/414074/mount-cifs-host-is-down)

> This could be also because of protocol mismatch. In 2017 Microsoft
>   patched Windows Servers and advised to disable the SMB1 protocol.
>
> From now on, mount.cifs might have problems with protocol negotiation.
>
> The error displayed is "Host is down." but when you do debug with:
>
> ```
> smbclient -L <server_ip> -U <username> -d 256
> ```
>
> you will get the error:
>
> ```
> protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
> ```

The post mentions that Windows patches to the protocol/Wannacry and others, are messing up with/or more exactly, some people disabled v1 CIFS requests functionality; similar problems have been happening on the Windows front, and, given the timing, it makes me suspect the problem must be related.

We have not disabled v1 CIFS in this specific server, AFAIK (and testing confirms this), however the MS bulletins suggest the default SMBv1 behaviour was (slightly) changed.

I ended up following the general idea suggested in the mentioned Samba question. From [man `mounts.cifs`](https://man.cx/mount.cifs):

> `vers=`
>
>   SMB protocol version. Allowed values are:
>
> - 1.0 - The classic CIFS/SMBv1 protocol. This is the default.
> - 2.0 - The SMBv2.002 protocol. This was initially introduced in Windows Vista Service Pack 1, and Windows Server 2008. Note that
>     the initial release version of Windows Vista spoke a slightly different dialect (2.000) that is not supported.
> - 2.1 - The SMBv2.1 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2.
> - 3.0 - The SMBv3.0 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.
>
> Note too that while this option governs the protocol version used, not all features of each version are available.
>
> `--verbose`
>
>   Print additional debugging information for the mount. Note that this parameter must be specified before the
>   `-o`
>   . For example:
>
> ```
>  mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt --verbose -o user=username
> ```
>
> As seen by the manual, in recent Windows versions after Windows 8
>   using at least `vers=2.0` may make more sense; the alternative syntax in the
>   command line with the `--verbose` option that is mentioned is also be
>   useful to further debug any complication that may arise.

As such, as the Windows server which I am mounting stuff from on this question is a Windows server 2008 R2, I put in `/etc/fstab`:

`//10.2.1.2/XX/ZZ/YY    /mnt/mount_point        cifs    credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=2.1 0 0`

Then remounted it for the option to take effect:

```
sudo mount -o remount /mnt/mount_point
```

Now we verify, with `mount` again, to confirm the negotiated protocol:

`$mount
//10.2.1.2/XX/ZZ/YY on /mnt/mount_point type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=2.1,cache=strict,username=someusername,domain=XXX,uid=1001,forceuid,gid=1001,forcegid,addr=10.2.1.2,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=61440,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`

And we can indeed confirm we modified successfully the SMB protocol being used.

See also [MS Developer Network - [MS-SMB2]: Versioning and Capability Negotiation - 1.7 Versioning and Capability Negotiation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246492.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

It should also be noted CIFS v1.0, besides being obsolete, is extremely inefficient and insecure, compared to newer versions of the protocol.

From [MS blogs - Stop using SMB1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2016/09/16/stop-using-smb1/)

> **SMB1 isn’t modern or efficient**
>   When you use SMB1, you lose key
>   performance and productivity optimizations for end users.
>
> - Larger reads and writes (2.02+) – more efficient use of faster networks
>     or higher latency WANs. Large MTU support.
> - Peer caching of folder and
>     file properties (2.02+) – clients keep local copies of folders and
>     files via BranchCache
> - Durable handles (2.02, 2.1) – allow for
>     connection to transparently reconnect to the server if there is a
>     temporary disconnection
> - Client oplock leasing model (2.02+) – limits
>     the data transferred between the client and server, improving
>     performance on high-latency networks and increasing SMB server
>     scalability
> - Multichannel & SMB Direct (3.0+) – aggregation of network
>     bandwidth and fault tolerance if multiple paths are available between
>     client and server, plus usage of modern ultra-high throughout RDMA
>     infrastructure
> - Directory Leasing (3.0+) – Improves application
>     response times in branch offices through caching

Interestingly enough, this last article suggests the disconnections problems are less likely to appear after a disconnection (Durable handles) if using a protocol >= 2.01, so I would stress again, to not continue using CIFS v1.0. (e.g., while in 1.0, `echo_interval=60` does keep it connected, if there is a network glitch, or some other server interruption, the mount won't recover itself without manual intervention, while using CIFS v1.0)

As a last piece of advice, avoid doing `sudo mount -a`, and start doing:

```
sudo mount -o remount -a
```

See my question also [CIFS mounting multiple copies of the same share on the same mount point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367925/cifs-mounting-multiple-copies-of-the-same-share-on-the-same-mount-point)

Comment: I was able to mount successfully, But the mount will not be available after a while. if i try df -h the command completes in appx. 15 - 20 secs and then the mount point will not be there in the list. if i try to ls /mount_point  im getting "Host is down."  message. no clues though. 
Once im  getting this behavior i will not be able to remount. i need to restart the machine to mount again

Comment: @Shan There are a lot of variables on the equation, server side issues, networking issues, firewalling issues. These posts are breadcumbs, they wont automagically solve all complex problems, you have to follow the path of debugging them. While the vocation of the group is not debugging complex network situations for askers per se, if there are specific Unix doubts, try to describe well the issues; it would be better opening a new question.

Comment: Agreed, But I'm clueless with no logs or traces. anyway I have limited access to the shared folder in Windows. So I asked the team to check for any useful information. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Shan My non-technical opinion: my job has been for a decade supporting and being the interface in the linux/networking side for people like you. e.g. You would benefit enlisting the  help of more experienced  sysadmin/network people on your organization, or having outside consulting.