# How to check SMB connections and the dialect that is being used on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, arch-linux, samba

I want to check the  dialect version in SMB connections.

On Windows, `Get-SmbConnection` will get it.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SmbConnection
ServerName    ShareName     UserName     Credential   Dialect      NumOpens
----------    ---------     --------     ----------   -------      -------
savdal08r2    c$            SAVILLTEC... SAVILLTEC... 2.10         1
savdalfs01    c$            SAVILLTEC... SAVILLTEC... 3.00         1
```

on macOS,  `smbutil statshares  -a` works well.

What should I do on linux?

Comment: I forgot to explain that linux is a client and I mount the samba server with `mount.cifs -o user=xxx......`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are running a Samba server on Linux, `smbstatus` should show the protocol version used by each client.

If Linux is the client, it depends on which client you're using: if you're using the kernel-level `cifs` filesystem support, in all but quite new kernels, the answer was that you look into `/proc/mounts` to see if the mount options for that filesystem include a `vers=` option; if not, assume it uses SMB 1.

SMB protocol autonegotiation in kernel-level CIFS/SMB support is rather recent development, <strike>and as far as I know, if you don't specify the protocol version you want, the autonegotiation will only indicate the result if you enable CIFS debug messages.</strike> but fortunately the developers made it so the negotiation result will always be shown in `/proc/mounts`.

If you use `smbclient` or other userspace SMB/CIFS clients (e.g. one integrated to your desktop environment), then it might have its own tools and diagnostics.

Comment: The mount points show the version negotiated by default as far as I am aware, have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367884/cifs-randomly-losing-connection-to-windows-share

Comment: Thanks,I forgot to explain that linux is a client.i look into the manual of smbstatus  cifs-util and find nothing.I didn't expect it to exist in the mount.

Comment: "if the mount options for that filesystem include a `vers=` option; if not, assume it uses SMB 1". Do you happen to have a reference for this statement? For example, on https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFSKernel, I find this seemingly contradictory statement: "For improved security and performance, SMB3 is the now the default dialect (SMB3.1.1/SMB3.02/SMB3/SMB2.1 dialects are requested by default)."

Comment: @bers If the `cifs` filesystem supports autonegotiation, it will always show the `vers=` option according to the actual version negotiated, in `/proc/mounts`. If that option is not there, you're dealing with an old kernel that cannot autonegotiate and very likely defaults to SMB 1. In [kernel.org Git logs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/fs/cifs/connect.c?h=v5.7-rc4) the default was changed in 2017-07-08 and autonegotiation was added after that in 2017-09-17. Distributions may or may not have backported those patches both at once to their kernel pkgs.

Comment: thanks, @telcoM!

Comment: Add "-b" option; e.g "smbstatus -b" returns lines like this one: "1662    nobody  nogroup  <netBIOS_Name> (ipv4:192.168.1.100:48372)  SMB3_11"

Comment: @user2431763 You probably wanted to add this comment to [the answer of FreeSoftwareServers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478523/258991) and not to mine. Each answer has a separate "add a comment" link.

Comment: My `/proc/mounts` (Ubuntu 22.04) keeps showing `vers=default`. But the actual dialect negotiated / used can be queried via `/proc/fs/cifs/DebugData`.

Comment: @Stefan looks like the the recent kernels may have changed the behavior again, then.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a script that comes with nmap. nmap/Zenmap(GUI) will allow you to scan a single device or subnet range (your home or office network) and try and show you what SMB protocols are in use.

```
nmap --script smb-protocols 192.168.1.0/24
```

The big point here is to **cease using SMBv1** due to security concerns. It's also known as  '*NT LM 0.12*' 
Zenmap is available for most major platforms.

Comment: This shows SMB versions offered by the server, but not the actual SMB version used by an actual client-server connection.

Comment: This is what I needed! Had to add `-Pn` but then it showed:
Host script results:
| smb-protocols: 
|   dialects: 
|     2.02
|     2.10
|     3.00
|     3.02
|_    3.11

Answer (score 2):

Use `smbstatus` >>

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbstatus.1.html

Example Output:

```
[root@server~]# smbstatus --shares

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PubRO        26900   192.168.1.255 Thu Oct 25 12:43:51 AM 2018 PDT  -            -
```

Comment: How does `smbstatus` determine the CMB **version** that's in use?